# changing working directory changes the default gemset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I have this gemset that I use to develop my rails app, but currently it is not the default gemset everytime I open up a terminal window. I tried using the `rvm gemset use mygemset --default` command but no luck in making it work.

How can I set the default gemset automatically?

Comment: `--default` is not a command. What exactly have you tried?

Comment: sorry for not being precise... i was pertaining to this command. `rvm gemset use mygemset --default`

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth yes i am using rvm